# Projectile to clear a hemispherical mound

Tags: physics, kinematics

I have only just stumbled across this site a few days ago while searching for other things.  This is a great resource.  I have a question for nearly 30 years now when me and my friend were trying to solve the following question from the book "An introduction to the theory of mechanics" by K.E. Bullen.  I just fetched from the library a 7th edition copy and there on p.157, Question 19, it wrote:

A particle is projected from the highest point of a hemispherical mound of radius a.  Prove that it cannot clear the mound unless its initial speed exceeds sqrt(ag/2).

My friend and I worked out a very simple solution which got us the "answer" sqrt(ag/2).  However, we then realized we were definitely wrong.  But we didn't go on finding the correct one as it appeared to be too difficult for us.  Please solve it for me.

(It's my first question.  I may have made mistakes on tags, manner, etiquette ...  please go easy on me.)

Comment: Hello. Perhaps you should post this question on the following site: http://physics.stackexchange.com/. In any case, could you give more details? For instance, is there an information about the angle of launch, or is it free? What do you mean by clear the mound, is it getting down on the ground without touching the mound?

Comment: Oh, can i lodge a question at multiple sites?  Thanks for your advice.

And regarding more information, although the question is written as is on the text, you can assume that one could fire at any angle.  You just need to find the minimum launch velocity just to clear the mound.  (And as I wrote to Martigan below, it should clear the mound at a point other than (a,0))

So, one could in principle find the minimum velocity to clear the mound as a function of launch angle.  And then find the minimum of this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of projection is minimal when the projectile just grazes the mound, or equivalently when the projectile fired tangentially to the mound in a vertical plane hits the apex of the mound. Taking the projection point as $(-a\sin\theta,a\cos\theta)$, with the $y$ axis vertical through the centre of the mound, the trajectory in this plane is given by $$y-a\cos\theta=(x+a\sin\theta)\tan\theta-\frac{g(x+a\sin\theta)^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta},$$where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity and $v$ is the speed of projection. Substituting in $x=0$ and $y=a$ (the apex) gives, after simplification, $$\frac{2v^2}{ga}=1+\sec\theta.$$ The speed $u$ at the apex is given by $v^2=u^2+2ga(1-\cos\theta)$, or$$u^2=\frac{ga}2(4\cos\theta+\sec\theta-3).$$To minimize this, differentiate with respect to $\theta$ and equate to zero, giving$$-4\sin\theta+\sec\theta\tan\theta=0,$$or $\theta=\frac13\pi.$ Finally, this gives $u^2=\frac12ga$ or $u=\sqrt{\frac12ga}$.

Comment: For this method, I think we also want to know that $u$ is minimized exactly when $v$ is minimized. Presumably it is not hard to show.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidK, for pointing out my error. I hope that the answer is is OK now.

Comment: Wow!!  That's great!  As I wrote to Martigan in the comment section of the question, my friend and I followed that solution path and got us entangled in complicated algebra which we could not solve.  Of course, our problem was that we attacked from the launch point.  Here is a much better way of thinking by going from the grazing point.  A neat solution even I could understand and possibly repeat ... after some 30 years.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the launch is lateral, the problem is fairly easy.

Let's have $y(t)$ the height of the projectile and $x(t)$ its lateral position, with $(0,0)$ being the center of the hemishparical mound of radius $a$.

Then you have $y(t)=-\frac 12 gt^2 + y(0)$ and $x(t)=v_0t$ (with $y(0)=a$)

Then the projectile hits the ground at $t=t_1$ when $y(t_1)=0$, that is

$-\frac 12 gt_1^2 + a=0$ or $t_1=\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{g}}$

Then $x(t_1)=v_0\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{g}}$

But we want $x(t_1) \geq a$ So the limit case is

$v_0\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{g}}=a$ or $v_0=\sqrt{\dfrac{ag}{2}}$

Comment: That's the solution my friend and I arrived at years back.  Then we decided it could not be correct as it cannot hit the mound at (a,0).  The slope of a parabolic projectile is not vertical at that point while that of the mound is vertical.

Comment: Thx for your attempt by the way.

Comment: @WilliamHa The point cannot be reached this way. Because it is easy to see that whatever the trajectory, the slope of the projectile will never be vertical at the point $(a,0)$.

Comment: so, we thought it should clear the mound at a point other than (a,0).  And it would therefore land at (b,0) where b>a.

Answer (score 0):

While the given solutions do provide the correct answer, there is a slightly simpler and more intuitive way to solve this problem.

Take the characteristic equation for projectile motion (derived from eliminating t from SUVAT equations) and set up a coordinate system centred on the centre of the mound.

Inserting the initial conditions, we get:

$$ y = a + x tan(\theta)- \frac {gx^2}{2u^2cos^2(\theta)} $$

To find the minimal velocity, we require that only one angle of theta minimises this equation. This can be done by treating the equation as a quadratic in $tan(\theta)$ and setting the discriminant to 0. Using an identity and working through some algebra:

$$ x^2 = \frac {2gx^2}{u^2} (\frac {gx^2}{2u^2} + y - a)$$

We rearrange to:

$$\frac {u^2}{2g} = \frac {g}{2u^2} x^2 +y - a $$

Thinking further about this, we realise that a minimal launch velocity to clear the mound also implies that the path of the projectile is tangential to the mound. This means that the path of the projectile just touches the mound or that there is only one solution to the intersection of the 2 curves (one for the projectile, one for the mound).

Now we must remember our hemisphere is described by $x^2 + y^2 = a^2 $ and so we can substitute this for x^2. We can  have a quadratic in y and we can take the discriminant. Setting this to 0 means only one solution to the intersection between projectile and mound and so the projectile is, as required, tangential to the mound.

$$ \frac {g}{2u^2} y^2 - y + a + \frac {u^2}{2g} - \frac {a^2g}{2u^2} = 0 $$

Taking the discriminant of this, we obtain:

$$ 1 = \frac {2g}{u^2} (a + \frac {u^2}{2g} - \frac {a^2g}{2u^2}) $$

$$ \frac {u^2}{2g} = a + \frac {u^2}{2g} - \frac {a^2g}{2u^2} $$

$$ \frac {ag} {2u^2} = 1 $$

$$ u = \sqrt{ \frac {ag} {2} } $$